# Forwarding mail automatically

Tags: vba, outlook

I receive emails with subjects of the form “### auto fax” where “###” is a variable number of digits.  Each of these emails must be forwarded to “###@mail2fax.com”.  I am looking for ideas on how to automate this.

Comment: consider adding proper tags into questions

Comment: The example you give can easily be achieved with a rule.  If Subject = "xxxxxx" then Forward to "yyyyyy@yyyyyyy" is an easy rule to create.  If your requirement is more complex than this, you will need to expand your question.

Comment: It’s more complicated because I have fax number in the mail subject. And I want it to be sent to a mail that is like : “fax_number@mail2fax.com”.

Comment: So it takes the number from the subject and passes it into the recipient. It’s not preknown recipient.

Comment: Is this correct?  The subject will be if the form:  "???? auto fax" where "????" is four digits.  You want the email to be forwarded to "????@fax.com" or "????@mail2fax.com".

Comment: What don't you know?  Do you know how to use VBA to forward an email?  I suspect that attaching a macro to a rule will be the easiest way of achieving your objective. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @TonyDallimore you right I need this macro to attach to a rule. The macro needs to strip the subject take the digits from the subject and add to the digits (4 or more) the “@example.com” (just to show you the I want to make general macro and give it specific things later).

Comment: I think that it may be simpler than what I think but I am really new to that and don’t know what to do.

Comment: I will try to describe with example: the mail received has subject:”*** ###” (where *** is the digits that will used for mail recipient, not limited for 3 digits, and ### is trigger for outlook rule). The macro will take the digits and add pre chosen extension to it like “@example.com” (same extension all the time). Than it will pass it to the rule that will forward the received mail to this mail address.

Comment: Please do not give examples. Please say explicitly what you are attempting to achieve. I have edited your question to include what I think you want. Please delete your text and my heading and then correct my text to create a new question. My text defines a simple, unambiguous requirement. If your requirement is more complicated, I suggest you do not add those complications. A short question is more likely to be answered than a long question. An answer to my question may not give you everything you need but it will give a lot of what you need.

Comment: @TonyDallimore you got the exact idea. Thanks for helping out

Comment: I know you will receive a message telling you about this comment.  I do not know if you will receive a message telling you I have added part 2 of my answer.  This comment is to make sure, you know about part 2 of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your addition “and it needs me to be at office” may be a problem.  I am a home user of Outlook.  If I want Outlook to do any while I am away, I need to leave my computer switched on.  I assume you are an Outlook Exchange user.  You can leave instructions that will be obeyed while you are away even if your computer is switched.  However, for security reasons, the default is that you cannot leave instructions to forward an email outside your company.  As I understand it, you would need to forward the “Auto fax” emails to a colleague.  Since we hope to automate the process, this should not be an imposition on your colleague.  You would need to create a version of your rule and macro and install it on your colleague’s computer but this should not be too difficult if my reading of this functionality is correct.  The point is, that this will not be part of this answer.

A difficulty with VBA is that there are usually several ways of achieving the same effect.  This does not matter if you develop your own VBA; pick your favourite way of achieving an effect and experiment until you have a full understanding of that favourite.  However, if you ask for help or look for useful snippets of code, you must have a basic familiarity with every way of achieving effects because others will not share your favourite.  You may find you have to get the idea of what a snippet does and then rewrite it your way.  This code is written using my favourite techniques.

When you write a macro to process emails, you have two issues:

- How do you select the emails you wish to process?
- How do you process the selected emails?

There are four methods of selecting emails:

1. The user selects one or more emails and then runs the processing macro.
2. The macro scans one or more folders looking for emails with particular characteristics and then processes them.
3. You instruct Outlook to monitor a particular folder and to run a macro every time a new email arrives in that folder.
4. You set up a rule to select emails as the arrive and link a macro to that rule to process them.

I believe method 4 will be the easiest method to implement your requirement.  However, it may not be available.  It works fine on my system but apparently those responsible for an Outlook Exchange installation can forbidden it.  If method 4 does not work for you, I believe method 3 will be the next best method.  However, this answer will use method 1.

I use method 1 whenever I am developing a new email processing macro.  If gives me total control of which emails are processed in which order.  I can start with simple emails and I can run the macro against the same email again and again until I get the macro working just the way I want.  Once I am satisfied with the macro, I can switch to whichever of the other methods is most appropriate.

This is the first version of my processing macro:

```
Public Sub ForwardAndMoveEmail(ByRef ItemCrnt As Object)

  Dim FaxNum As String
  Dim ItemNew As MailItem
  Dim Subject As String

  If ItemCrnt.Class <> olMail Then
    ' Ignore item if it is not an email
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Subject = ItemCrnt.Subject
  If LCase(Right$(Subject, 9)) = " auto fax" Then
    ‘ Only process email if the subject ends with case-insensitive " auto fax"
    FaxNum = Mid$(Subject, 1, Len(Subject) - 9)
    With ItemCrnt
      Subject = "Fax from " & .Sender & " (" & .SenderEmailAddress & ")"
      Set ItemNew = .Forward
    End With
    With ItemNew
      .Subject = Subject
      ' Clear existing recipient(s)
      Do While .Recipients.Count > 0
        .Recipients.Remove (1)
      Loop
      .Recipients.Add FaxNum & "@mail2fax.com"
      .Save
    End With
  End If

  ItemCrnt.Move ItemCrnt.Parent.Parent.Folders("Faxed")

End Sub
```

The item to be processed is a parameter to this macro.  Note that I have typed it as an Object rather than as a MailItem.  Then note that the first statements of the macro checks that the item is a `MailItem` (`Class = olMail`).  With method 1, the user could select something other than a `MailItem`.  This check ensures this user error causes no problem for the macro.

Next the macro checks the Subject ends in “ auto fax” or “ Auto fax” or “ AUTO FAX” or any other variation.  With method 1, the user could select the wrong `MailItem`.  With method 3, every email is passed to the macro.  Hence, the check that it is a macro to be forwarded to the fax service.

If I decided in advance which selection method I was going to use, I would not need to perform all these checks.  I think that being able to change the selection method is worth the extra checks.

The macro extracts the leading characters of the Subject.  I do not check that they are numeric although such a check could be added if it was important.

The macro creates a new Subject for the forwarded email.  I do not know if you would want a new Subject but this demonstrates what you can do if it was helpful.

`Set ItemNew = .Forward` creates the item to be forwarded.  Note that this statement is within a `With` block.  This is the same as `Set ItemNew = ItemCrnt.Forward`.

The macro then works on `ItemNew`.  It changes the Subject, it clears the existing recipients and adds the new one and then saves the new email as a draft.

The last statement of the macro is something else you did not ask for but which may be useful.  I have created a folder named “Faxed” and I move the original email to it.  This saves the original email without cluttering your Inbox.

Consider `ItemCrnt.Parent.Parent.Folders("Faxed")`.  This is the folder to which the item is to be moved.  I have chained properties together in a way that probably looks strange but is straightforward once you understand it.

- `ItemCrnt` is the original mail item.
- `ItemCrnt.Parent` is a property of `ItemCrnt`.  Many objects have parents.  For a `MailItem` it is the folder holding the `MailItem`; that is, folder “Inbox”.
- `ItemCrnt.Parent.Parent is a property of folder “Inbox”.  For a folder, its parent is the folder containing it.  Since folder “Inbox” is a top-level folder, its parent is the store holding it.  A “store” is a file in which Outlook stores folders, mail items, calendar items, tasks and many other things.
- Having gone all the way up to the store, `ItemCrnt.Parent.Parent.Folders("Faxed")` goes down to a folder within the store.

The macro that calls ForwardAndMoveEmail is:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SelectEmailsUser()

  Dim Exp As Explorer
  Dim ItemCrnt As Object
  Dim MailItemCrnt As Object

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  If Exp.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("Please select one or more emails then try again", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If
  For Each ItemCrnt In Exp.Selection
    If ItemCrnt.Class = olMail Then
      Call ForwardAndMoveEmail(ItemCrnt)
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Don’t worry too much about this macro at this stage.  Study it later when you are ready to develop your next processing email.  It is a macro I wrote a long time ago.  Each time I want to test a new email processing macro I simply change statement `Call ForwardAndMoveEmail(ItemCrnt)` to call the new macro.

This is not the final version of the processing macro although it is probably the final version of this evening.  Please:

- Copy the two macros to an Outlook module.  The two macros can be in either order but `Option Explicit` must be at the top of the module.
- Create folder “Faxed”. At the same level as folder “Inbox”.
- Select one or more of the “Auto fax” emails and run macro SelectEmailsUser.
- Check the processed “Auto fax” emails are now in folder “Faxed”.
- Review the emails in folder Drafts.  I think these emails are unsatisfactory.  I will tell why later and what I think you should do to make them satisfactory.

**Part 2**

I ended the first part of this answer by saying I did not think the draft email my macro had created was satisfactory.

The problem for me is that the original email is headed up by a typical “forwarded” header: original sender, my name, date sent and subject.  The author of the email has presumably spent some time creating the text of the email and would not want this irrelevant header prefixing their text.  So how was I to stop this header being included in the email sent to “mail2fax.com”?

My first idea was to use method “Copy” instead of method “Forward”.  This did give a satisfactory appearance but was slight awkward.  With the statement `Set ItemNew = ItemCrnt.Forward`, `ItemNew` is a draft email ready to be finished and saved in folder “Drafts” or sent.  But with the statement `Set ItemNew = ItemCrnt.Copy`, `ItemNew` is a received email and, when saved, is placed in folder “Inbox”.  I have sent a copied email and the appearance when it arrives at one of my secondary email addresses looks satisfactory.

My second idea needs an introduction.  An email can have three bodies: plain text, HTML or RTF.  I have never seen an email containing a RTF (Rich Text Format) body.  RTF was probably a sensible format 20 years ago if you wanted more that plain text.  But today, HTML is so powerful that the same email can be rearranged for a large PC screen, a tablet or a smart phone so it is always easy to read.  So for all practical purposes there are only two formats for an email: plain text and HTML.  If an email has both plain text and HTML bodies, it is the HTML body that is shown to the reader.  The VBA programmer can look at either or both bodies but the reader is not told that there is a plain text body.  Very occasionally, I have seen a carefully constructed plain text body that has been designed for an email package that cannot handle HTML.  But normally the plain text body is just the HTML body with the HTML tags stripped out.

My second idea was to use method “Forward” but then to copy the text and HTML bodies from the original email.

In the above code, you will find:

```
.Subject = Subject
' Clear existing recipient(s)
```

Please replace these two lines with:

```
.Subject = Subject
.Body = ItemCrnt.Body
.HtmlBody = ItemCrnt.HtmlBody
' Clear existing recipients
```

With this change, the draft emails will not have a “forwarded” header.

I assume you know who these emails are being faxed to.  I suggest you contact one or two and say you are going to conduct an experiment.  They will have already received faxes as a result of you using the keyboard interface to forward these emails.  Send some of the draft emails created by my macro and ask for the recipients’ opinion on the new appearance.  If they prefer the new appearance, we will be ready to move on to stage 3: Automating these emails.  If they do not like the new appearance, you will need to ask them what is wrong about the new appearance and we will have to attempt to fix the problem.

**Part 3**

Please do not follow the instructions in this part until you are convinced that emails created by macro `ForwardAndMoveEmail` are as they should be.  This part is about automating the process so the emails will be sent without you having any opportunity to check or correct them before they are sent.

Please make the following changes to macro `ForwardAndMoveEmail`:

Replace `Public Sub ForwardAndMoveEmail(ByRef ItemCrnt As Object)`

by `Public Sub ForwardAndMoveEmail(ByRef ItemCrnt As MailItem)`.

With email selection method 1, it is possible (difficult but possible) to select items that are not `MailItems`s.  I set the type of `ItemCrnt` to `Object` so this would not cause an error.  To use a macro with a rule, `ItemCrnt` must be `MailItem`.

These statements are now redundant:

```
If ItemCrnt.Class <> olMail Then
  ' Ignore item if it is not an email
  Exit Sub
End If
```

You can leave these statements since they will do no harm.  Alternatively, you could delete them or place a quote in front of each statement.

Replace `.Save` by `.Send`.

On my system I can attach a macro to a rule.  If you can do the same, it will be the easiest approach.  However, some IT departments consider attaching a macro to a rule to be a security risk and disable it.  If you find you cannot attach a macro to a rule, you will have to try the event approach.  I will add additional instructions if necessary.

The screenshots below are from my home Outlook installation.  You have functionality I lack so the screens you see will not be identical.  However, my screenshots should be similar enough to yours to be useful.

Select one of these “auto fax” emails.  From the “Home” tab click “Rules” then “Create Rule...”.  You will get a pop-up window like this:

[image: First screen of Create a rule]

I created an “Auto fax” email in one of my secondary accounts and sent it to me main account.  This is why I am shown as both the sender and the receiver.  Because I had selected the “Auto fax” email, its subject is shown.  Edit this subject to remove the leading digits. A tick will appear in the box next to the subject to get:

[image: First screen of Create a rule after editing]

Click “Advanced Options...” to get this pop-up window:

[image: Second screen of Create a rule]

Notice that subject in the line near the top has not been edited.  This does not matter; it is the value in the “Step 2” box that matters.  Note that if you click “ Auto fax” in the “Step 2” box, you can add extra values.  So if some of these emails have slightly different subjects, you can add these alternative values.  Click “Next” to get a pop-up window like this:

[image: Third screen of Create a rule]

Near the bottom is “Run a script”.  You will have more options and may have to scroll down to see this option.  Click the box next to this option.  “Run a script” will appear in the “Step 2” box.  Click “Run a script” in the “Step 2” box.  You will be asked to “Enable macros” if you have not done so already.  A new pop-up window will appear showing all the macros that could be selected for this option.  I have several possible macros so I will not show you my list.  You should only see one macro: `ForwardAndMoveEmail`.  To appear in this list, a macro must be `Public` and the first parameter must be a `MailItem`.  Select `ForwardAndMoveEmail` if it isn’t selected and click “OK”.  “Run a script” now reads “Run ForwardAndMoveEmail”.  Click “Next”.  You will get a pop-up window of exceptions which I assume are irrelevant to you.  Click “Next” to get the final pop-up:

[image: Final screen of Create a rule]

You can click the box against ‘Run this rule now on messages already in “Inbox”’ to forward any of “Auto fax” emails already received but not forwarded.  Click “Finish”.

The “Auto fax” rule is now operational and any “Auto fax” emails will be forwarded automatically.  It would be a good idea to monitor folder “Faxed” and check the intended recipients received their faxes.